# How i can upload nested JSON and create a table using java in Athena

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

How i can upload nested JSON and create a table using java in Athena with the help of data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe(maven)?
or is it possible to do so?

Comment: Don't ask open ended generic questions. Show what you tried, which documentation or tutorial you're following and then ask help on the specific issue you're facing. Not a problem statement of a project.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.